# Induced EMF in magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields

An emf may be induced in
(a) a piece of linear wire when it moves in a uniform static
magnetic field; 
5
(b) a closed loop of wire moving with a fixed orientation at
a constant velocity in a non-uniform static magnetic
field;
(c) a closed loop of wire moving with a fixed orientation
and accelerating in a uniform static magnetic field;
 (d) the cases described in (a) and (b) only;
 (e) the cases described in (b) and (c) only

The correct answer is (d), but I thought that option (c) is also correct, since the emf induced is derivative of magnetic flux, and this is clearly changing since the loop is accelerating in some direction. Can someone please explain why this is wrong (and why only (a), (b) are correct)?

Comment: The magnetic field is uniform and static. Whether the loop is stationary or in motion, the magnetic flux will always just be **$A \cdot B$**, where $A$ is the area of the loop. That won't change just because youre accelerating.

Comment: But doesn't the option of (c) do the same as option (a), since although the magnetic fields are uniform, they both "cut" out a certain area in time t?